# How to append multiple excel template with data in one printing

Tags: c#, winforms, export-to-excel

I am working on Windows form application C# and have encountered a problem in exporting data to excel. I don't have enough knowledge about this and I don't know if it is possible. I tried searching about this and I can't seem to compose my question properly. I just want to know if this is possible and if there are documents about this.

I have a template:
Excel template:
[image: excel template]

and this is the print/output that I wanted in one paper:
Print output:
[image: print output]

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `How do I achieve this?` You should retrieve your data from database, if your data is stored in database, then export it to excel. Short answer is - yes, this is a doable job. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at following demo. I made it simple.

Create a WinForms project (in this example it's name is WindowsFormsApp3).

Create a strongly-typed data set - `ProductsDataSet`.

[image]

Add a new static class `Extensions` to the project

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    static class Extensions
    {       

    }
}
```

Insert into this class following 2 methods

First method

```
private static void Export(this ProductsDataSet dataSet, Worksheet worksheet)
{
    var products = dataSet.Product.Select();

    for (int i = 1, j = 6; i < products.Length; i++, j += 5)
    {
        worksheet.Range["A1", "D4"].Copy(Type.Missing);
        worksheet.Range[$"A{j}"].PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAll,
            XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,
            true, Type.Missing);
    }

    for (int i = 0, j = 3; i < products.Length; i++, j += 5)
    {
        worksheet.Range[$"B{j}"].Value = products[i][0];
        worksheet.Range[$"C{j}"].Value = products[i][1];
    }
}
```

Second method

```
public static void Export(this ProductsDataSet dataSet, string fileName)
{
    Application application = new Application();
    var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(fileName,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing
        );
    dataSet.Export((Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1]);
    application.Visible = true;
}
```

Customize `Form1` as below

[image]

Subscribe following event handler to button's click event.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        switch (openFileDialog.ShowDialog())
        {
            case DialogResult.OK:

                var directoryName = System.IO.Path
                        .GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog.FileName);
                var fileName = System.IO.Path
                        .GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName);
                var destFileName = 
                        $"{directoryName}\\{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.{fileName}";
                System.IO.File.Copy(openFileDialog.FileName, destFileName);
                productsDataSet1.Export(destFileName);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I created following excel template file, similar to yours. The program will open this file and populate it with data from `productsDataSet1`.

[image]

Here is running application

[image]

Here is exported data in the excel file

[image]

Comment: Woah! this is so great and readable, I'll try this. Thankyouu